# JQueryUI- Can options take more than one parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make my draggables snap to each other as well as their containing div. Is this possible? this works:

```
$($element).draggable({         
            snap: true          
        })
```

but this (and variations of it) will not:

```
$($element).draggable({
            snap: true, '#mainwindow'
        })
```

Anyone know how to give options more than one parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQueryUI website, the [example with snap on draggable()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to) has the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({ snap: true });
  $("#draggable2").draggable({ snap: '.ui-widget-header' });
  $("#draggable3").draggable({ snap: '.ui-widget-header', snapMode: 'outer' });
  $("#draggable4").draggable({ grid: [20,20] });
  $("#draggable5").draggable({ grid: [80, 80] });
 });
</script>
```

So I think `snap: '#mainwindow'` might do the trick. Also, I haven't tried this so I'm not sure if its possible (others can correct me since I'm not familiar with jQueryUI, although it looks awesome) but what if you create a callback function to handle the snap event:

```
$($element).draggable({
   snap: function(event, ui) {/* insert functionality */}
});
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want, since I have to hard code the snapping myself but I think it's about as good as it will get. Thanks, Hristo.

Comment: :D You're welcome I guess. I guess you could look at the source code for the snapping to make it easier (if you actually do the snapping yourself).

Answer (score 0):

```
$($element).draggable({
            snap: true, '#mainwindow'
        })
```

This example isn't legal JavaScript/JSON.  You would need something like...

```
{
  snap: [true, '#mainwindow']
}
```

Which I don't think draggable() will except.

> I'm trying to make my draggables snap
>   to each other as well as their
>   containing div.

Try giving each draggable and the containing div(s) a class like "snappable" and pass

```
{
  snap: ".snappable"
}
```